# Convert URL to correct filename (Linux/Windows)

Tags: php

I have a script that works with different sites. As a result this script returns 1 csv file for 1 site with a unique filename, based on site URL. Site URL may be different, like

```
http://test1.com
http://test2.com/testurl
http://test3.com/test/path/
```

I want to convert URLs to filenames - to remove all characters that can cause conflict in Linux/Windows, to replace them with '_', for example

```
http://test1.com will be test1com.csv
http://test2.com/testurl will be test2comtesturl.csv
http://test3.com/test/path/ will be test3comtestpath.csv
```

I can try to use parse_url and concat host and path with replacing '/' and '.' to '_', but I'm not sure that this is the best solution, because URLs can be different and with different characters that can not be used as filename.

Comment: Possible use of mod_rewrite?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: If you are using apache as your webserver you can do this sort of thing when the URL arrives at the site. More info [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: URLs list is stored in DB. I cannot understand how mod_rewrite can help me in convertation process. I thought that I need PHP solution. Tell me if I don't understand something.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list of URL-safe characters and convert any character that's not in the list into `_`.

Just be careful of duplicates (site.com/test/x and site.com/text.x, for example), if any. Find a way to handle them.

Comment: Do you know some function in PHP that can check if character is not allowed in current filesystem, where the script is executed? Or I should write this function myself?

Comment: I don't think there is such a function because we know where PHP ideally lives. You can go with something like alphanum ASCII characters, maybe make it convert the filename into camelCase and you'll never have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who uses python, I write a simple function

```
import string

class URLProcessor:
    def __init__(self, ):
        prohibited_fp_character = """#%&{{}}\<>*?/ $!'":@"""
        prohibited_fp_character_to_id = {}
        atoz = string.ascii_lowercase
        for id, c in enumerate(prohibited_fp_character):
            prohibited_fp_character_to_id[c] = "▁"+atoz[id]
        self.prohibited_fp_character_to_id = prohibited_fp_character_to_id
        self.id_to_prohibited_fp_character = {v: k for k,v in self.prohibited_fp_character_to_id.items()}

    def url_to_filename(self, url):
        fp = ""
        for c in url:
            if c in self.prohibited_fp_character_to_id:
                fp += self.prohibited_fp_character_to_id[c]
            else:
                fp += c
        return fp
    
    def filename_to_url(self, filename):
        url = ""
        repl = 0
        for c in filename:
            if c == "▁":
                repl = 1
            elif repl == 1:
                url += self.id_to_prohibited_fp_character["▁"+c]
                repl = 0
            else:
                url += c
        return url
```

Comment: the question is related to php not python. read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer